# wordpress search on multiple tables by default search query

Tags: database, wordpress, preg-replace

at least spending days in an MySQL nightmare hope someone can help me. I work on a tagging plugin for WP.

My problem sounds so easy: to keep the wordpress database clean and performant I decided to save additional fields (tags, titles, free text, urls, ...) in some extra tables and not adding typical meta fields. Now the search query must include these fields too.

After hours I found that ([geoteagging wordpress example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries)):

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'geotag_search_join' );
add_filter('posts_where', 'geotag_search_where' );
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'geotag_search_groupby' );
```

so far so good. Now its time to rewrite the query (geotag_search_where) but here the nightmare begins...

the custom table name is: "abc_tags" and the fields called "abc_title" and "abc_tags". 
"abc_tags" is a long text field with comma separated plain text items.

I dont understand the preg_replace manipulation with the query...I hope someone can help.

```
function geotag_search_where( $where )
{
  if( is_search() ) {
    $where = preg_replace(
       "/\(\s*post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
       "(post_title LIKE $1) OR (geotag_city LIKE $1) OR (geotag_state LIKE $1) OR (geotag_country LIKE $1)", $where );
   }

  return $where;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're taking the `$where` string in the search `SQL` and rather than making it only search for the `post_title` variable, they're appending to the MySQL query string with the addition of `geotag_city`, `geotag_state` or `geotag_country` to cross check for other matches.

This way if you search for *"New York"* it will return results where the geotag_city matches as well as the title. (It's not good form to list every possible keyword in a title.)